# How to reversely compute from hash

Tags: key-derivation, sha-256, secret-sharing, nonce

What are practical methodologies to derive the following ciphertext:

```
1bd0d370b262d748b21c40cc7e5746642b4c06079a224c65e443e429289753c2
```

Comment: I'm confused. What are you trying to derive? It looks to me like you know everything already.

Comment: Ok how about now?

Comment: The question is essentially ciphertext for an unstated algorithm, asking for the algorithm. That's squarely off-topic (and impossible without hints, not given). Besides, it got [explained by the makers](https://medium.com/algorand/algorands-instant-consensus-protocol-e66ac5807e37).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the feasible methods:

1. Ask the creator nicely or read their [blog](https://medium.com/algorand/algorands-instant-consensus-protocol-e66ac5807e37)
2. Search for the string on any major search engine (e.g., [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=1bd0d370b262d748b21c40cc7e5746642b4c06079a224c65e443e429289753c2&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS751US751&oq=1bd0d370b262d748b21c40cc7e5746642b4c06079a224c65e443e429289753c2&aqs=chrome..69i57.198j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).
3. Use [physical methods](https://xkcd.com/538/) on the person who derived the string.
4. If you have access to software that created it, reverse engineer it.

That is really about it, when it comes to feasible methods. If there was any sophistication at all going into the creation of the string (multiple hashes, nonces, random numbers, encodings, etc.), the number of possibilities are just too many to feasibly try them all.

Comment: Amazing answer! Never considered asking the creator as a feasible method :D
It's a shame I can only give you one upvote